How to create a module of constants accessible directly and through a dictionary
I want to create a module called 'constants.py' that contain all the constants specific to my system.
To offer flexibility I would like to be able to access the constants directly like this:
constants.power_1
constants.power_2
constants.data_rate_1
constants.data_rate_2
...

because it is short, or access the constants through a dictionary like this:
constants['system_1']['power']
constants['system_2']['power']
constants['system_1']['data_rate']
constants['system_2']['data_rate']
...

because it is useful when sometimes I use a constant inside a loop like this:
systems = ['system_1', 'system_2']
for system in systems:
    power = constants[system]['power']
    var_2 = var_1 * power

My problem is that I cannot use both methods at the same time.
What I can do:
Option 1. Forget about accessing a constant like constants.power_1, and have only a dictionary like constants['power_1']. So I declare them like this in 'constants.py':
constants['power_1'] = 10
constants['system_1']['power'] = constants['power_1']

and use them like this:
from constants import *
var_2 = var_1 * constants['power_1']
var_2 = var_1 * constants['system_1']['power']

Cons:

I don't really like the import *, even if I import only one dictionary, I prefer a simple import.
The direct access is 4 characters longer (['']).

Option 2. Use an intermediate name for my dictionary. So I declare them like this in 'constants.py':
power_1 = 10
varname['system 1']['power'] = power_1

and use them like this:
import constants
var_2 = var_1 * constants.power_1
var_2 = var_1 * constants.varname['system 1']['power']

Cons:

I don't find a meaningful name for varname, because it is not necessary (I could put system, but it is redundant).
The long access gets longer.

Do you see another way to solve this?

"To offer flexibility I would like to be able to access the constants directly like this" - what kind of 'flexibility'? What's not flexible about just using the dictionary? If all you're doing is trying to save someone a few characters of typing, please stop - you're wasting your time and the result will be bad code.

If you insist on have both types of access, you could define a class that allows you access to the constant value defined as named variables (note that there's no such thing as a constant, you can name your variable in capitals to indicate its intended use as such). But also keep in mind that you could also write a class that actually functions as a container of constants that can't be changed directly, and functions just like a dictionary, which may be closer to what you really want.

Normally you create constants in classes or enums. As they provide autocomplete.

use getattr to access your "dotted" object properties in a loop

To be honest, if you wanted to do this I would recommend creating a class-based structure, that will provide a dictionary-like structure for hierarchical constants, and a flat namespace for individual constants.
Constants.py could look something like
class Constants:
def __init__(self):
    # flat - you can also maybe load this from a JSON so you don't touch this often
    self._flat_constants = {
        "power_1": 10,
        "power_2": 20,
        "data_rate_1": 100,
        "data_rate_2": 200,
    }
    
    # heirachy
    self._nested_constants = {
        "system_1": {
            "power": self._flat_constants["power_1"],
            "data_rate": self._flat_constants["data_rate_1"],
        },
        "system_2": {
            "power": self._flat_constants["power_2"],
            "data_rate": self._flat_constants["data_rate_2"],
        },
    }

def __getitem__(self, key):
    # First look through the flat ones
    if key in self._flat_constants:
        return self._flat_constants[key]
    
    # Then check nested ones
    if key in self._nested_constants:
        return self._nested_constants[key]
    
    raise KeyError(f"Constant '{key}' not found.")

def __getattr__(self, name):
    # Allow direct access to flat constants
    if name in self._flat_constants:
        return self._flat_constants[name]
    
    raise AttributeError(f"'Constants' object has no attribute '{name}'")

Then you can just use it by initializing wherever you plan to, knowing that you can use the dot to access the flat constants (constants.power_1), and the ['system_1]['power'] to access the nested ones.
Tip: If you eventually decide to load from a JSON, you should add some logic to raise an exception if duplicates are found in the keys (duplicates are allowed in JSON).

Thank you very this very detailed answer! However, to use this class, I cannot do: Constants.power_1, because it results in the error "type object 'Constants' has no attribute 'power_1'". I need to create an object, which I don't want: o = Constants(), print(o.power_1)

You can create an instance of the class (e.g. constants = Constants()) from within the same file, then export it.
So you can use that instance like => from constants_module import constants. After which constants.power_1 can work.

Ah yes, I didn't think of that... Thank you!
